# How to have operator<< for specific template instantiation std::tuple<double, int, int>?

Tags: c++, c++14

How to create `operator<<` for specific `std::tuple<double, int, int>` template instantiation?

```cpp
using FST = std::tuple<double, int, int>;


std::string TupleAsStr(const FST & i) {
    return "(" +
           std::to_string(std::get<0>(i)) + ", " +
           std::to_string(std::get<1>(i)) + ", " +
           std::to_string(std::get<2>(i)) +
           ")";
}

// what I have
FST const& fst = std::make_tuple(1.0, 4, 5);
std::cout << TupleAsStr(fst) << std::endl;

// what I want
std::cout << fst << std::endl;
```

I don't need generic solution for N types, just for this specific case.

Comment: It is probably not a great idea to overload an operator using only standard types. What if someone else that uses your code or whose code you use also wanted to implement streaming tuples? At least put the overload in a `namespace` you own.

Comment: You are probably better off making `FST` a proper `class` and overload `operator<<`.

Comment: Thanks @FrançoisAndrieux for info about the namespace. I'm using this code only for debugging so it will endup surrounded by `#ifdef`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overload `operator<<` for the `FST` type. Also, it's better to put the `FST` type into a namespace as well, to avoid collisions with existing overloads:

```
namespace my {
    using FST = std::tuple<double, int, int>;

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const my::FST & i) {
        return out << "(" <<
           std::to_string(std::get<0>(i)) << ", " <<
           std::to_string(std::get<1>(i)) << ", " <<
           std::to_string(std::get<2>(i)) <<
           ")";
    }
}
```

and then do `using my::operator<<` when you want to use it.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7o3G37).